# Delaying a click event with .delay()

Tags: jquery, delay, timedelay

I have a button that gets triggered by the click of another button. I want to delay click of the second button for two seconds. I used .delay() but it didn't work.

```
jq(function() {
      jq('a.box').click(function() {
         jq(this).closest('.button').find('.add_this').delay(2000).click();
      })
    });
```

or Using setTimeout;

```
jq(function() {
      jq('a.box').click(function() {
      setTimeout(function(){
         jq(this).closest('.button').find('.add_this').click();
      },800);
      });
    });
```

But didn't work.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

from the docs http://api.jquery.com/delay/

> The .delay() method is best for delaying between queued jQuery
>   effects. Because it is limited—it doesn't, for example, offer a way to
>   cancel the delay—.delay() is not a replacement for JavaScript's native
>   setTimeout function, which may be more appropriate for certain use
>   cases.

you can use `setTimeout` to bind click handler after a delay

```
setTimeout(function(){

jq('a.box').closest('.button').find('.add_this').click();
},2000);
```

EDIT

```
jq(function() {
      jq('a.kklike-box').click(function() {
      $this = $(this);
      setTimeout(function(){
         $this.closest('.deal_buttons').find('.add_this').click();
      },800);
      });
    });
```